# How to correctly burn-in Hebrewe captions in AWS Mediaconvert

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-media-convert

Am trying to burn-in hebrew captions on a video using AWS mediaconvert but, it comes out in reversed order (note that it's RTL direction)

I have the captions in `.srt` and it looks correct in the file

what are possible solutions to fix this ?